# How to accept null value in <p:spinner>

Tags: jsf, primefaces, null, spinner, bean-validation

I'd like to be able de add constraint validation(`@NotNull` and `@digits`) on value of PrimeFaces 3.4 `<p:spinner>`,  but when we set it to empty it's reset to 0 value. It cannot take null. Is it possible to change this behavior?

```
<p:spinner id="spin" value="#{myBean.spinValue}" min="0" max="23"/>
```

in MyBean:

```
@NotNull(message = MessageList.requiredMessage)
@Digits(integer = 2, fraction = 0, message = MessageList.converterMessage)
@Min(value = 0, message = MessageList.validatorMessage)
@Max(value = 23, message = MessageList.validatorMessage)

private Integer spinValue;
//Setter and Getter
```

Comment: Before attempting the validation, when the spinner component loses focus it's reset to 0. What i really need is how to avoid to process and change spinner value before submitting the form.Any idea?

Comment: I've found this issue in Primefaces "Issue 5387"...